# give user input when writing a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, github

I am running a bash script that automatically clones a git repo.make the changes in the provided git repo and then push those changes to github.now when i am cloning the repo it asks me for my username and i don't know how to provide these inputs in a bash script.for privileges i am blacking out some things.but i will explain the rest of it to you.i have tried git config but it won't work.can somebody please help me with this

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
appName=$(echo xxxxx/xxxxx)
echo $appName
version=`echo "$BRANCH_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER" | tr / -`
echo $version
imageName=$appName:$version
echo $imageName
git config --global user.name "xxxxxxxx"
git config --global user.email "xxxxxxxxxxx"
git config --global user.password "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
git clone https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git
cd qa-namespace/red/website-manager
sed -i "s|\(image[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*\)\(.*\)|\1'${imageName}'|"  input deployment.yaml
git add .
git commit -m "changed name of the branch"
git push
```

Comment: Use an [SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Comment: Use `$()` instead of backticks consistently.

Comment: `appName=$(echo xxxxx/xxxxx)` is better written as `appName=xxxx/xxxx`

Comment: Note that no part of standard Git ever uses, or even checks for, a `user.password` setting.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks for the advice but my issue is with git

Answer (score 0):

You should change `git clone https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git` into `git clone https://<USER_NAME>:<USER_PASSWORD>@github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git`

Comment: Hi antonio,i have an @ in my password therefore it is showing this errorfatal: unable to access 'https://2019@github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxx.git/': Could not resolve host: 2019@github.com

Comment: I suggest you to change you password.